# Attempt to query out data in CSV using Python failing

Tags: python, csv, operators

I am working with a CSV file in which I need to eliminate some data by attributes. In the code I am successfully eliminating the val[0] AK from writing to my file. However, I need to query out val[2] if it is less than 200 hectares.

I am not getting an error message with this code but it is not querying out the hectares.

I've adjusted my code in a few different ways - I am new at this. I previously was getting error messages such as cannot convert string to float....after messing around with this I no longer get any error message - but do not get the needed results.

```
def write_files(lg_fire_data, combined):
        # Want the first header 
    with open(lg_fire_data[0], 'r') as first:
        combined.write(first.read())

    for i in range(1, len(lg_fire_data)):
        with open(lg_fire_data[i], 'r') as canada_vals:
            next(canada_vals, None)

            for val in canada_vals:
                if val[0] != 'AK':
                    combined.write(val)

            for val in canada_vals:
                val[2] = float(val[2])
                if val[2] >= 200:
                    combined.write(val)
```

I no longer get any error message - but do not get the data queried out.

Help is appreciated...hypothetically I'd think this should be simple. :)

Comment: `for val in canada_vals:
            if val[0]` : this reads the first character, not first cell, as you didn't use `csv` module but plain text io which reads line by line and yields strings. So no line match

Comment: and the second loop does nothing because data has been already iterated upon.

Answer (score 0):

first you're forgetting to create a `csv.reader` object with the file handle, so your first loop yields *strings* not *rows*. And `val[0]` is a *character*.

Then you cannot search twice on an iterator, the second time the iterator has been consumed and the second loop does nothing. If you want to perform 2 loops, store the contents of the rows in a `list`

```
import csv

for file in lg_fire_data:
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        canada_vals = csv.reader(f,delimiter=',')  # not sure of your csv delimiter
        next(canada_vals, None)  # read title

        canada_vals = list(canada_vals)  # create a list, so you can loop twice
        # rest is okay
        for val in canada_vals:
            if val[0] != 'AK':
                combined.write(val)

        for val in canada_vals:
            val[2] = float(val[2])
            if val[2] >= 200:
                combined.write(val)
```

Comment: GREAT - thanks, I'll try this. One fundamental question....do I need to state the reader / writer in each 'def' statement or does python know it was declared before? Just curious.....

Comment: I know I don't know much about python. My work has me doing stuff WAY over my head... so dumb list question...Here is my list list = ['Province','Fire_ID','Hectares','Longitude','Latitude'] and it was inserted just about canada_vals=list..etc... I'm getting TypeError: 'list' object is not callable. I'm guessing I don't know how to write a correct list? (I also tried an empty list of list = [] same error. :(

Comment: Corrected my list call to reflect canada_list = ['Province',Fire_ID, etc]  (I spotted they syntax typo above.) Now I am getting  errorValueError: could not convert string to float o on the line of  val[2] = float(val[2]).

Comment: I have 0 province name...string / 1 fire id....string / 2 hectares....float / 3 longitude....float / 4 latitude.....float.  Ack! This is literally the last little thing on this script then it's done :)  Is my canada_list calling by column names correct or should I do something like using val[0], val[1], etc. in the list itself?   Just so you know I REALLY APPRECIATE the help!